# "Could not find a Web server at: <WRONG URL!>" when opening pages in designer

Tags: url

So I'm running SharePoint 2010 designer, and I'm getting this really stupid error.  Every time I try to open one of my site pages it gives me this error:

> "Could not find a Web server at: 'url'. Please check to make sure that
>   the Web server name is valid and your proxy settings are set
>   correctly. If you are sure that everything is correct, the Web server
>   may be temporarily out of service."

The stupid thing is that it's right - the web server that it's displaying DOESN'T EXIST! It's tacking on a "-dev" to the end of my URL for some odd reason, which makes it an incorrect web address.  Looking under the page properties, it's got the correct URL listed there and everything.  I have no idea why it is doing that or where to fix it since everything seems fine. I mean, I've opened the right website to get there in the first place, after all.

Does anybody have any ideas? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your alternate access mappings in central administration. You should have one internal URL entry for the default zone of the web application.

Comment: keyword there is default zone. Make sure you are using the default zone URL.